# Determine Maximum Possible DIV Height

Tags: javascript, css, dom, browser, cross-browser

Is there a recommended way to determine the maximum height that a DIV can be set and remain visible per browser? This doesn't appear to be documented anywhere and is highly implementation specific.

For example, see the following test script:

http://jsfiddle.net/NP5Pa/2/

This is a simple test to find the maximum value you can set a DIV style height attribute before the corresponding `clientHeight` of the element becomes 0. You can confirm this by clicking "Find Max" then incrementing the found height by 1 and clicking "Set Height".

Some examples (Win7/64):

```
Chrome (14.0) :    134,217,726 px
Safari (5.1)  :    134,217,726 px
IE (9.0)      :     10,737,418 px
FF (7.0.1)    :     17,895,697 px
```

It's not surprising the WebKit produces the same result, I guess - more surprising that IE and FF are so different.

Is there a better way? And do you get different results in 32bit systems?

*--EDIT: Updated the fiddle to stop at 10,000,000,000 (and get there quicker) for Opera. That's a lot of pixels.*

Comment: I have to upvote this question simply due to how obscure it is.

Comment: Yeah I know, it came up in a real world situation though ('virtual' scrollers on datagrids for very large tables).

Comment: Your demo never seems to end in Opera. It appears that `clientHeight` is never set to `0`.

Comment: Updated it as per the comment. Is it visible at that size?

Comment: Credit to opera for not having a max. 10 million microsoft? That's easily exceeded in a comment thread when people complain about font changes on facebook. /troll

Comment: @Hamish: Your updated demo works as expected in Opera. Yes, it's still visible.

Comment: @thirtydot thanks! I wonder if it is actually getting that big, or if Opera is sensible enough to think about the edge case and limit it so it remains visible. Either way, go Opera!

Comment: Off late chrome (ver 21) seems to be supporting max 35791389px only, 1/3rd of the earlier max

Comment: @Hamish May I ask how you solved the max height issue with virtual scrolling?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is your code, modified to use binary search (so it's much quicker).

http://jsfiddle.net/thai/zkuGv/4/

It begins at 1 pixel and doubling its size until the it hits the maximum (I use 2<sup>53</sup>, which is the biggest integer that can be stored in JavaScript without losing precision and would make the binary search buggy), or the div collapses to zero pixel.

Suppose we set the div to size *h* and it disappears, then the maximum size must be between *h*/2 and *h*. We binary search from there for a height *h* that does not make the div disappear when set to height *h*, but disappears when set to *h*+1.

Then we can come to a conclusion for Opera: 2147483583 pixels.

Comment: This js fiddle was very helpful, but an interesting thing I found is that after a certain point, browsers seem to have some maximum height they will set the div to and just clip anything larger to that height - and at a later point, we see 0-height divs.  But it's the clipping that causes problems for me.

Here's a slightly tweaked version of the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zkuGv/16/

I've tested with Chrome and IE 11 and came up with the following numbers:

- Chrome is fine until 25,165,824px
- IE 11 has problems at 1,533,917px

I really doubt the number is in the billions for Opera.

Comment: Based on my own testing with react-virtualized I think Chrome is up to ~33.5 million now. At least that's where `scrollTop` is being stopped at. You can position items further down (at least a little bit) using `top` but you won't be able to scroll to them.

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted, while you can make elements very tall, they won't be usable after a certain height, depending on what you're doing.

Modifying [Thai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7756428/418057) jsfiddle to have text at the bottom:

```
<div id="inner" style="position: relative;">
  <div style="position:absolute; bottom:0;">
    === BOTTOM ===
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8kjstu4x/

Now:

- Make the height 30000000 (30 million), scroll down, text is still there.
- Make the height 40000000 (40 million), scroll down, text is gone.

I've also noticed, that after a height of around 16 million pixels, things start going wrong.  Missing borders, alignment issues, etc.

Comment: This is a really interesting addition to this (old) question. So there is still undefined browser-specific behaviour here, in 2021!

Comment: @Hamish Sure is.  Although, it should also be noted, that once you reach such large heights, your users won't be having the best experience with the scrollbar.  So, probably time for a redesign.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here try this: http://jsfiddle.net/serkanyersen/yNfuX/

It will respect the parent's padding and margin properties. When you click MAX button, DIV will expand to most available space. I'm sure you can convert this according to your needs.

It actually needs to be recursive, starting from itself to the very top, but I didn't have time to implement that.

NOTE: Try resizing the page, and uncomment the parent DIV to see it fully work.

Comment: "Remain visible" part is confusing. Apparently this is not the answer you are looking for.