# Size Comparison

Tags: javascript, math, size

See my code: http://jsfiddle.net/NxNXJ/5

The star should be the same size as the sun at this link: http://astro.unl.edu/naap/hr/animations/hrExplorer.html, but this is not happening.

I'm not able to solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/NxNXJ/6/)

Your `calc` method should multiply val by the size of the sun, so that for example calc(1) returns a width equal to the sun's width, calc(2) returns a width twice that of the sun, etc.

If you want the star to be initialized with the same size as the sun, set the slider's initial value to 0 and call `showBall(0)`. This will set the star's size equal to the sun's because 10^0 = 1, so the star's size will be the sun's size times 1.

Comment: Hi..
I did what you said but see: http://jsfiddle.net/NxNXJ/8/
The star continues with different size.

I tried it: showBall(-2); and value:0, but the initial value of the slider changes for 0.010 and the correct is 1.0

Thanks

Comment: You should rewrite your `calc` method to `return num * 150;` instead of `num * 10,000`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/NxNXJ/6/

Comment: But by manipulating the slider until the end of the circle that represents the star disappears or does a different motion.
See: http://jsfiddle.net/NxNXJ/13/
Unlike this: http://astro.unl.edu/naap/hr/animations/hrExplorer.html

Comment: I suspect that the star disappears because its height exceeds some hard limit imposed by the browser. See [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719273/determine-maximum-possible-div-height). On my browser, the star disappears at around luminosity 50,000, equivalent to about 7 million pixels tall. Regardless, the slider problems you're now having probably deserve their own question, as they aren't directly related to this post's  problem (IMO).