# CSS what are possible issues with huge element width (100.000+px)?

Tags: css

What are the theoretical problems with hugely wide elements, like the image container of a carousel element. Are there any reasons why there would be a difference between a fixed container width of 10,000px or 1,000,000px ? At what point does performance become a realistic issue?

I am aware there are better ways to do this in practice (like calculating the width dynamically). I'm just interested in the maximums and problems related to huge elements.

Comment: Typically the problems will be related to memory consumption and more precisely how the particular browser handle this large number of elements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have an exact number, it depends on OS memory management, browser memory management, physical memory, occupied memory (number of tabs and other running apps) and so on.

To be sure you don't grind the browser (or OS) to a halt, and if you really must have a container that large, make sure to use some kind of lazy load for the content. An empty div is not a problem.

See this question for some numbers [Determine Maximum Possible DIV Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719273/determine-maximum-possible-div-height)

Comment: The link provided some concrete numbers I was after. Even though width / height are different from rendering point of view, the magnitudes and differences are probably similar on different browsers.

Answer (score 3):

I just tested this at 10,000px, 100,000px, and 1,000,000px. It renders the same within a millisecond.  I used google developer tools in Chrome.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div style="width:100000px;background:#000;height:100000px;">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
</html>
```