# Internet Explorer 10, max div size of 1.533.917 px

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html, size

I need to make a really big div, in order of millions of pixels.

Searching I found this thread that proves that IE can manage up to 10.000.000 of px.

[Determine Maximum Possible DIV Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719273/determine-maximum-possible-div-height)

But in my test IE 10 can't size a div more than 1.533.917 px.

This is my test: [jsfiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/KRAYx/4/)

The value between brackets is the size that I try to set and the previous value is the computed size of the div calculated with jquery.

The question is: Why IE can't size a div more than 1.533.917 px in my test?

This is the js that makes the div bigger:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var interval = setInterval(function () {

        height  += 10000;
        width   += 10000;

        $(".sujeto").css({width: width, height: height});
        $(".contador").text( "Width: " + ( $(".sujeto").width() ) + "px (" + width + ") - Height: " + ( $(".sujeto").height() ) + "px (" + height + ")");

    }, 100);

});
```

Comment: On my screen 1.533.917 px makes about 300 meters, that's a lot of scrolling... ; )

Comment: @Teemu: Reminds me of all those wiggle the joystick C64 olympic games!

Comment: lol wow, why would anybody **need** to have an element this size?

Comment: @Teemu is for a project that makes a galaxy with zoom. Make a div of 4.000.000 of px make the code more simple

Comment: @user2550196 Have you tried to position an element at `top: 4000000px;`?

Comment: @Teemu there is no scroll in the project. the control is make dragging and with the mouse wheel.
And yes, I tried it. But don't worry, there is no scroll in my project :)

Comment: It's possible that you're hitting some limit based on the maximum texture size of your graphics card. But either way, you probably should consider a different design.

Comment: This limit is the same with transparent / no style div. Running the test with a diferent (and moooore expensive) graphic card gives the same results. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: I suppose that i will rewrite the code and keep in mind this limit.

Answer (score 0):

Any solution for this scenario.Below link demonstrates the problem exactly.
The example not created by me Nathan Williams.

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; overflow: auto;">
    <div style="width: 500px; height: 10000000px; overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
        <span style="left: 0px; top: 0px; position: absolute;">top</span>
        <span style="left: 0px; top: 1193030px; position: absolute;">IE8 limit (approximate)</span>
        <span style="left: 0px; top: 1533900px; position: absolute;">IE10 limit (approximate)</span>
        <span style="left: 0px; top: 9999950px; position: absolute;">bottom</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bckbr/