# IE fundamental limit of scrollTop in a large scrollable div

Tags: html, internet-explorer, scrolltop

I have a viewport div containing a very large scrolling div with elements absolutely positioned inside.  (These are recycled and repositioned as the viewport scrolls so the number of elements to manage remains small even with a large data set.)  In Firefox and Chrome, I can scroll within the viewport all the way to the bottom, even when the contained div is millions of pixels tall.  However, in IE, there seems to be a limit to how far the scrolling div is able to scroll.

In IE10, the max is around 1533900 pixels.  Scrolling to the bottom reveals an element positioned at the limit, but elements farther down are inaccessible.  In IE8 on WinXP, it's even less (~1193030 pixels).  These numbers are not close to a conventional integer overflow limit, so I'm wondering if they are specified by any standard or by Microsoft.

There are other ways to implement scrolling in a large data set, but this approach has the benefit of entirely native scrollbar behavior.  If there's a fundamental limit to it in IE though, I'd like to understand it better.

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; overflow: auto;">
    <div style="width: 500px; height: 10000000px; overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
        <span style="left: 0px; top: 0px; position: absolute;">top</span>
        <span style="left: 0px; top: 1193030px; position: absolute;">IE8 limit (approximate)</span>
        <span style="left: 0px; top: 1533900px; position: absolute;">IE10 limit (approximate)</span>
        <span style="left: 0px; top: 9999950px; position: absolute;">bottom</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bckbr/

Comment: Why would you need to load so much data into one page?

Comment: A [dup](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17472708/1169519)?

Comment: It's log data, fewer than 100K lines, which is still a lot but not outrageous.  The isssue Teemu linked does appear to be the same thing.

Comment: For me the limit is 1533033 on IE 11. In Firefox 66.0.5 and Chrome 74.0.3729.157 it is OK. Seems like a bug.