# Testing website on different resolutions

Tags: html, asp.net, internet-explorer, browser

I have a small question about Internet Explorer. I have IE10 installed on my development machine and now testing my website on different resolutions through IE development toolbar. I test website also on some custom resolutions and have seen that height of the web document (clientHeight) could not be more than 1040px regardless I set 1100px, 1200px, 1300px or whatever else.

Is there some restriction existing in Internet Explorer (some setting in Windows registry or similar)? Could someone explain?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the resolution of your computer screen? If you're running on 1920x1080 or something then you are not going to get a browser window more than 1080 in height (and if you take off space for task bar, title bar, etc. 1040 sounds like a feasible number).

Comment: I have 2 displays: 1920x1200 and 1920x1080. So I test on a bigger one (1920x1200).

Comment: IE has a limit, but it's [much higher](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472708/internet-explorer-10-max-div-size-of-1-533-917-px).

Comment: Yeee. but there a talk ("much higher" link) about <DIV> size which is content inside of Internet Explorer. And I'm trying to change the actual size of Internet Explorer window. I think such big size of a <DIV> could be because of "scrolling", not because IE window could be so big.

Comment: It's not clear, to which exactly object you're using `clientHeight`. What ever it was, `clientHeight` is read-only for those objects supporting it. You can set the size of a window with `resizeTo()` or `resizeBy()` methods of `window` (if allowed in Internet Options), but not by changing _any_ property value. Even using these methods you can't grow the window taller than available height on a screen. If you need more info, please post more code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I just use addons for testing web-pages with different resolutions. Particularly web developer extension that exists for Chrome, Opera and Firefox. And for Internet Explorer I use developer tools included already in IE. So on the display 1920x1200 Chrome and Opera (height of window) can be expanded to 1222px (more than screen resolution, according web developer extension measurements). Firefox to 1020px and Internet Explorer 1091px. It is a little bit interesting why none of browsers expands to 1200px but this is not the worlds most important things to know.