# virtual scroll wrong display in IE missing rows

Tags: javascript

i have this script for virtual scroll and for some reason after about 68500 rows it breaks in Internet Explorer 11,but works in FF and Chrome...

```
https://jsfiddle.net/dLq2284r/5/
```

at the end you can see the rows overlap .., but only after over 65k rows
i think something is wrong here:

```
 positionPage: function(inPage)
```

t is getting quite big :) over 1535274
so i think setting a css top : 1535274px; or more is the problem, but i might be wrong :D

```
positionPage: function(inPage) {
var pn = inPage.pageNum;
if (this.fixedHeight) {
  t = pn * this.rowHeight * this.pageSize;
} else {
  if (this.pageTops[pn]) {
    t = this.pageTops[pn];
  } else {
    var n = 0, t = 0; 
    while (n < pn) {
      t += this.getPageHeight(n);
      n++;
    }
  }
}
var t0 = inPage.style[this.horiz ? 'left' : 'top'].slice(0, -2);
// update pageTops cache
this.pageTops[pn] = t;
this.pageTops[pn+1] = t + this.getPageHeight(pn);
// set the page's top
inPage.style[this.horiz ? 'left' : 'top'] = t + 'px';
if (t0) {
  return t0 - t;
}
}
```

I have tried everything... any help, hints or anything will be appreciated.

I use this for a database with over 90k rows and i would love it to work on IE for at least 100k rows.

Also don't suggest frameworks or anything else, i have tried them all

Thanks

Comment: Looks like an IE bug/problem. Another example to reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/FPkxn/2/

Comment: The problem is not the wrong height, i had that problem too and managed to solve it by using a table (in that situation the scroll ended before i could reach the end of the table), the strange thing is that the page should look OK, but it's just like IE hits a limit...

Comment: look at https://jsfiddle.net/dLq2284r/7/   i set a console log to display current page and pixels height, everything should be where it should :D, also if you change the count variable to 70k or 80k the last row is always 68509... and if it were a element height problem i think that number should be different

Comment: I think it is an IE limit as well, that's what I mean with "IE bug/problem". If you change the count variable it's always limited to the same height, check the results when the lineheight differs. For instances div and p instead of table: https://jsfiddle.net/e00yzehp/

Comment: OK,I'll go with that :) and display a warning over 60k lines for IE ... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IE has a long way to go before can compete with other browsers .. So to answer my own question, based on @Sam Segers comment and my research it seems that after a specific height IE has a height miscalculation, based on

[Determine Maximum Possible DIV Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719273/determine-maximum-possible-div-height)

IE can handle about 10M pixels, but after about 1.5M it is not accurate, for example my element had a style top: 1535274px; and the browser was adding the content at 1534484px, so 790px higher, and my js stop working after that point. And since until that height everything was ok i concluded that my script is doing it's job.

I just added a warning in my script to let the IE users know that after that height results are not accurate and to use another browser.

Thank you for your help